# Flutter GridView off screen widgets destroyed on scroll

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a screen with a GridView widget containing custom Cards with images and texts. When the app initially launches it loads all the cards and their images, however, they get destroyed when scrolled off the screen. Is there a way that I can stop flutter from destroying the off-screen widgets?

```
Expanded(
 child: GridView.builder(
 gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  childAspectRatio: 1.5,
 ),
  itemCount: categories.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => CategoryCard(
   category: categories[index],
  ),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! GridView, ListView, etc., have **addAutomaticKeepAlives** and **cacheExtent** properties. By default `addAutomaticKeepAlives: true` doesn't destroy off-screen widgets, and providing the `cacheExtent: DOUBLE VALUE` describes how many pixels the cache area extends before the leading edge and after the trailing edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Give flex or   shrinkWrap: true, or use both

```
Expanded(
   flex: 3, <--
child: GridView.builder(
     shrinkWrap: true,  <--
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  childAspectRatio: 1.5,
    ),
 itemCount: categories.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => CategoryCard(
 category: categories[index],
   ),
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer as to why it would/should work? It did not work though!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).